# Clearing CSS styles due to second CSS file with some duplicate classes

Tags: css

Is there a global way to clear CSS styles from a div because of duplicate style names? We're merging content and are trying to minimize the work by utilizing multiple style sheets. Here's a test I've been working on: http://jsfiddle.net/Codewalker/yU2sW/7/. However, since it's JSFiddle, instead of referencing two external stylesheets, I've combined them in the CSS window. Notice how the secondary_container div inherits the blue text from the other container. I've also pasted the code below:

```
<div class="container">
<h1>This is in an h1 tag.</h1>
<p>This is at the very top, outside the secondary_container stuff. All kinds of content     can go down here. All of this is within a paragraph tag. I'll write one more sentence then     copy all this over again. Sound good? Wait that's two more sentences. Actually four. Oh well. So much for that. Here goes a little copying and pasting. All kinds of content can go down here. All of this is within a paragraph tag. I'll write one more sentence then copy all this over again. Sound good? Wait that's two more sentences. Actually four. Oh well. So much for that. Here goes a little copying and pasting.</p>

<div id="secondary_container">
<div class="container">

<p>This is within the container div that's within the secondery_container div. All kinds of content can go down here. All of this is within a paragraph tag. I'll write one more sentence then copy all this over again. Sound good? Wait that's two more sentences. Actually four. Oh well. So much for that. Here goes a little copying and pasting. All kinds of content can go down here. All of this is within a paragraph tag. I'll write one more sentence then copy all this over again. Sound good? Wait that's two more sentences. Actually four. Oh well. So much for that. Here goes a little copying and pasting.</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Here's the CSS, which would actually be two separate external stylesheets:

```
/* BEGINNING OF FIRST CSS FILE styler.css */

.container {
background-color: #00FF00;
height: auto;
width:960px;
margin: 0 auto;
line-height: 20px;
}

h1 { font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; color: #F00; text-transform:uppercase; }
p { font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; color:#00F; 

}

/* BEGINNING OF SECOND CSS FILE secondary_container.css 
*/

#secondary_container .container h1 { font-family:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif; color: #0F0; }
#secondary_container .container p { font-style:italic; line-height:14px;}
```

Comment: whichever one you include second should override the first.  so if you don't want aspects of the first just reset them in the second.

Comment: I don't see how those overlap.  The first CSS file will apply to all, but the second CSS file would override the first (if loaded second) for the secondary_container.

Comment: U can manage '!important' param, to avoid overlaping. http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/02/the-important-css-declaration-how-and-when-to-use-it/

Comment: Just to say it: No, there's no "global" way to do it.

Comment: I think I just realized what you are trying to do.  You know how to apply new styles, but you don't want any of the other styles to still apply but you don't want to specifically clear each of the prior values.  Right?

Comment: davids - That is correct. Once we get to the secondary_container div, I don't want any of the global, or container styles to apply. I basically need the CSS slate wiped clean.

Comment: So I did some reading and there doesn't seem to be a way to tell a certain div to ignore one stylesheet and only apply the styles from another stylesheet. For the custom-named divs, I could manually change them by prepending them like this:
original class name: container
modified class name: sec_container

For selectors such as body, h1, a, p, etc., I supposed I could prepend each definition with "#secondary_container a" to select the appropriate elements.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a bit of a clash of name space, ideally if thought out well you shouldn't get to this situation. Either be more precise, or rather, be less vague. You can wrap elements in separate divs for example, or use css chaining.

CSS has many useful snippets you can use if you do run into trouble such as `>`, which when used like so `div > p.myClass`, will only apply to `p`'s with a class of `myClass`, that are children of a `div`. You could then even make it more specific by using the `:first-child`, selector which means it will only apply to the first `p` tag, with a class of `.myClass`, that is a child of a div. `div > p.myClass:first-child`.

Really if there is no styling attributes required from the class, why use it?

Comment: Actually, I inherited this situation and the many duplicate classes.

Comment: In which case, I feel for you - not a nice situation!

Comment: You asked a good question: "Really if there is no styling attributes required from the class, why use it?". In my test, I have a div called #secondary_container that contains no attributes. The purpose for this was to be able to separate the container class from within it by referencing it this way (#secondary_container .container h1), but obviously that's not working.